# android upload image using http POST (php) and store the path on mySql, how to show it on the activity while saving it on the cache?

Tags: php, android, image

I want user to upload a profile picture (by camera / gallery) and then show it as user's profile photo on the application. (it is a social application). and also i want it to be saved on cache memory since application does not has to download it when ever the user use the application.

Q 1. How can i upload a image to the web server? with http post method and store the image path on sql. 
Q 2. How can i show the image on the activities used on the application.
Q 3. How to save the image on the cache?

please advice me or help me with coding if u may please.

thank you alot.

Comment: any of those links on the right help?

Comment: can help with the Q1 n Q2 but not with Q3

Comment: what cache are you referring to?

Comment: yes please. i can get it uploaded... save the path to the mysql somehow. but cache it n download it. use the cache and if not available again download function

Answer (score 0):

@Loshi here is how I upload Audio to my server located on Webhost.com. Chang what you need to upload Image, hope this helps. What I do here is save my file to sd card then upload to server in 1 single click.

```
public class Audiofileload extends Activity
{


private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
private static String mFileName = null;

private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;
private Upload   Upload = null;


private void onRecord(boolean start) {
    if (start) {
        startRecording();
    } else {
        stopRecording();
    }
}

private void onPlay(boolean start) {
    if (start) {
        startPlaying();
    } else {
        stopPlaying();
    }
}

private void startPlaying() {
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
}

private void stopPlaying() {
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
}

private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);



    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}


class Upload extends Button {
    boolean Upload = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream inStream = null;
            String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/testin.mp4";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;  
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
            String responseFromServer = "";
            String urlString = "http://sirisak.comule.com/11409.php"; 
            try
            {
              CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName) );
             // open a URL connection to the Servlet
             URL url = new URL(urlString);
             // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             // Allow Inputs
             conn.setDoInput(true);
             // Allow Outputs
             conn.setDoOutput(true);
             // Don't use a cached copy.
             conn.setUseCaches(false);
             // Use a post method.
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
             dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             // create a buffer of maximum size
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
             // read file and write it into form...
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
             while (bytesRead > 0)
             {
              dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
             }
             // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
             // close streams
             Log.e("Debug","File is written");
             fileInputStream.close();
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex)
            {
                 Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                 Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
             read the SERVER RESPONSE
            try {
                  inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
                  String str;

                  while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
                  {
                       Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
                  }
                  inStream.close();

            }
            catch (IOException ioex){
                 Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }
         }
    };

    public Upload(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Upload");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
} 





class RecordButton extends Button {
    boolean mStartRecording = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onRecord(mStartRecording);
            if (mStartRecording) {
                setText("Stop recording");
            } else {
                setText("Start recording");
            }
            mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
        }
    };

    public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Start recording");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}



class PlayButton extends Button {
    boolean mStartPlaying = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onPlay(mStartPlaying);
            if (mStartPlaying) {

                setText("Stop playing");
            } else {
                setText("Start playing");
            }
            mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
        }
    };

    public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Start playing");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}

public Audiofileload() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/testin.mp4";
}

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

    mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
    ll.addView(mRecordButton,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));


    mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
    ll.addView(mPlayButton,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));

    Upload = new Upload(this);
    ll.addView(Upload,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));
    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kasiriss);

    setContentView(ll);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ohh ok.. so u save it on the sd card b4 sending http post ri8... kool thnx

Comment: You got it, if that answered your question don't forget to let let community know.

Comment: And if you just dump the code into your project you can test it by going to http://sirisak.comule.com/11409/testing.mp4 to hear the audio. That's if anybody else needs the help.

Comment: and what about the images of the other users? how can it get to the phone?

Comment: That would depend on the structure of your application, you could load the images from the server.